# Excel formula using LARGE with if statements on multiple arrays

Tags: excel-formula

I want to find the **`nth largest value`** among an array and one additional cell, and the array needs to have some values excluded.

Excel seems to work fine when i joint arrays or when i do if statements on a single array but not when i do both.

I did `= LARGE( (A1, IF(B2:B5<>10,A2:A5) ),2)` and it returns me value error

Sorry it should have be something like this:
**I should not have used A1, that's really my bad. More accurately it would be : `D15 = Large ( (A15, if(B$2:B$5<>10, A$2:A$5),2)` and I need this to be a dragable formula going down to D16, D17 and so on **

Comment: Can you please explain why you have A1 in your formula? Should it be `= LARGE( (IF(B2:B5<>10,A2:A5) ),2)` without A1? If so I know where went wrong.

Comment: I should not have used A1, that's really my bad. This isn't exactly my formula more accurately it would be : D15 =  Large ( (A15, if(B$2:B$5<>10, A$2:A$5),2) and I need this to be a dragable formula going down to D16, D17 and so on

Comment: I still not sure why you have A15 in the formula. `=LARGE(array, k)` is the correct way of using this formula. You need to refer to a range but in your formula you put (A15, if(B$2:B$5<>10, A$2:A$5) which will not return an array. Did you mean IF(B$2:B$5<>10, A$2:A$5, A15)? i.e. if none of the value in range B2:B5 equals to 10, it will return range A2:A5, otherwise return A15? Are you able to show some screenshots of what is in B2:B5, A2:A5, and A15?